# Android: Calling an activity from a Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-intent

My problem is probably going to be simple and awkward at the same time, but I am a little stuck.

I have a Main.java class, that extends Activity.

Inside that class, I do the following:

```
ringerServer = new Thread(new RingerServer());
ringerServer.start();
```

What I want to do is have the RingerServer thread running continously.

Inside that thread, I listen for a TCP connection. If I get one, I start another class, which sends and receives UDP packet.

```
public class RingerServer implements Runnable {

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 4445; // Default port to connect to

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Create a socket for handling incoming requests
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);

            while (!VoIPCall.onCall) {
                // Wait for an incoming connection
                Socket clientSocket = server.accept();

                // TODO: Display a message for the user to accept or decline

                // For now, automatically accept the call
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(null, VoIPCall.class);
                // Put the IP as a parameter
                myIntent.putExtra("inetAddress", clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem has to do with the lines:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(null, VoIPCall.class);
myIntent.putExtra("inetAddress", clientSocket.getInetAddress());
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Those lines would work fine inside an Activity but it doesn't to complain as it is a Thread, it doesn't know about the Activity class, because it doesn't extend it, but implements Runnable.

I am not sure how I can make my program keep running the RingerServer but have the main thread go to VoIPCall class. Any ideas please?

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you very much,

Jary

Comment: One problem in your code is that you are passing null as the context to your Intent.  You need to pass it an actual Context object for that call to work.  If you want your Thread to be a separate class, then you probably should create a constructor that takes a Context as its argument.  You can pass in the Activity or Service instance  that is instantiating the Thread into the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your thread into a [Service](http://ttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) rather than an Activity.  I recommend starting off by reading the [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#procthread) section of the Android Dev Guide.  Then checkout the API docs for [Service](http://ttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), which will help you get started creating one.

Comment: I've read the difference between Threads and Processes, and started reading services, but it says: "A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors)." I don't understand why my RingerServer should be moved to a Service, rather than a thread because of that statement. Could you please explain the reasoning to me?

Comment: The lifecycle of an Activity is dependent on the user's interaction with it.  Once the user has moved away from the Activity, it is in danger of being killed by the Android framework.  On the other hand, a Service's lifecycle is not tied to interaction with the user and is meant to perform long running operations.  You will still need to create a Thread within your service though.  Looper, Handler, and HandlerThread are some classes worth considering for this purpose.